# want to set session timeout for mongodb atlas url

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, settimeout, mongodb-atlas

I want to implement a session time out for mongodb atlas URL so that it will get expire after specified time.

mongodb+srv://:@<>.azure.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
How are you trying to connect to MongoDB, which packages are being used? Would be good if you provide a little glimpse of the code

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve?

The localLogicalSessionTimeoutMinutes parameter needs to be set for each mongod instance in a deployment and is not a parameter currently available in the Atlas UI or API. I believe this is only suggested for testing as there will be unexpected consequences if the value isn’t set consistently in a deployment. This parameter determines when an inactive session is eligible to be cleaned up by the server so is generally a housekeeping parameter rather than a tuneable for performance or privacy.